# In iOS 7 how to auto-show keyboard for UIWebView containing a contenteditable div

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIWebView in which there is nothing but an contenteditable div. I want to auto-show the keyboard when the viewcontroller is loaded.

I have googled a solution using

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').focus()"];
```

But it does not work on my phone, which runs iOS 7.

I noticed the Evernote app, which makes the keyboard auto-showed, so I believe there is some method.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the first responder on the uiwebview in viewWillAppear

[self.myWebView becomeFirstResponder];